# Jet 4.0 split on delimiter

Tags: sql, split, jet

I am using Jet 4.0 to return a result. A set of result rows may look something like this:

```
EV1.EV2.EV3
EV4
EV5.EV6
```

the length of the result prior to the "." can be different.

Is it possible to take each string before the "." and use it in a join.

I have a table called EVInfo and Results. I want to join the fields in EVInfo to the results table for each EV occurance.